# Get indices aligned right in a customized 3-columned bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

does anybody know who to get the bibliography indices **aligned left**?

As you see in the picture, the indices ([ 1]...[9]) aren't aligned left:
[image]
In the end, it should be looking like this (the indices are aligned left): 
[image]
Here's my code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{mwe2012,
  author  = {Smith, A. and Johnson, B. and Willians, C.},
  title   = {The three most common surnames in the United States of America},
  journal = {Review of Useless Knowledge},
  year    = {2012},
  volume  = {8},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {290--290},
}
@ARTICLE{mwe2011,
  author  = {Miller, J. and Brown, D.},
  title   = {Most used surnames in fake passports},
  journal = {Journal of Nosense Ranks},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {5},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1--130},
  pmid    = {1234567},
  url     = {http://www.mwe.com/mwe2011},
  doi     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/jnr.2011.01.01},
}
@ARTICLE{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@ARTICLE{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@ARTICLE{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}

@ARTICLE{temperaturmesstechnik_endres,
  Title                    = {Temperaturmesstechnik. Thermometer und Transmitter für die Prozessindustrie},

  Author                   = {{Endress \& Hauser Messtechnik GmbH \& Co. KG}},
  HowPublished             = {online},
  Year                     = {2015},

  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.06.07},
  Url                      = {http://pdf.directindustry.de/pdf/endress-hauser/temperaturmesstechnik-thermometer-transmitter-prozessindustrie/4726-73446.html}
}

@ARTICLE{motorsensor_agt,
  Title                    = {Wie wird ein T3-Fühler eingesetzt und was sagt sein Signal aus?},

  Author                   = {{EngineSens Motorsensor GmbH}},
  HowPublished             = {online},
  Year                     = {2015},

  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.05.25},
  Url                      = {http://www.motorsensor.de/html/egt-messung.html}
}

@ARTICLE{motorsensor_einbaupositionen,
  Title                    = {Messpunkte der Gastemperatur bei modernen Verbrennungsmotoren},

  Author                   = {{EngineSens Motorsensor GmbH}},
  HowPublished             = {online},
  Year                     = {2015},

  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.05.30},
  Url                      = {http://www.motorsensor.de/html/abgastemperatur.html}
}

@ARTICLE{Audi_V6_biturbo,
  Title                    = {Das neue V6-Biturbo-Aggregat für den Audi RS4},
  Author                   = {Erdmann, H.-D. and Eiser, A. and Geiger, U. and Heiduk, T.},
  Booktitle                = {MTZ - Motortechnische Zeitschrift},
  Year                     = {2000},
  Month                    = {Juli},
  Pages                    = {444-450},
  Publisher                = {Vieweg Verlag},
  Series                   = {7-8},
  Volume                   = {61},

  Doi                      = {10.1007/BF03226584},
  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.05.29},
  Url                      = {http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03226584}
}

@ARTICLE{Fisch2010,
  Title                    = {Maschinenbau},
  Author                   = {M. Fischer},
  Editor                   = {Verlag},
  Publisher                = {Verlag},
  Year                     = {2010},

  Owner                    = {fischermi},
  Timestamp                = {2014.12.04}
}

@ARTICLE{tabellenbuch,
  Title                    = {Tabellenbuch Metall},
  Author                   = {Fischer, U. and Gomeringer, R. and Heinzler, M. and Kilgus, R.},
  Publisher                = {Europa Lehrmittel},
  Year                     = {2011},

  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.06.09}
}

@ARTICLE{toleranzen_beim_drehen_hoerr,
  Title                    = {Unternehmenspräsentation},

  Author                   = {{Gebrüder Hörr GmbH}},
  HowPublished             = {online},
  Year                     = {2015},

  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.06.06},
  Url                      = {http://www.hoerr-metalltechnik.de/}
}

@ARTICLE{GOPPELT11,
  Title                    = {Neues Verfahren erfordert geringere Temperaturen beim Rußabbrand},

  Author                   = {{Goppelt}, G.},
  HowPublished             = {ATZonline.de},
  Month                    = {10},
  Year                     = {2011},

  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.05.24},
  Url                      = {http://www.springerprofessional.de/neues-verfahren-erfordert-geringere-temperaturen-beim-russabbrand-14649/3951292.html}
}

@ARTICLE{griffin_ts200,
  Title                    = {Second Generation Platinum RTD Exhaust Gas Temperature Sensor for -50°C to 1000°C Measurement},
  Author                   = {Griffin, J. and Wienand, K. and Baerts, C.},
  HowPublished             = {online},
  Language                 = {englisch},
  Month                    = {Mai},
  Note                     = {SAE Technical Paper 981419},
  Organization             = {Heraeus Sensor-Nite},
  Url                      = {http://papers.sae.org/981419/},
  Year                     = {1998},

  Doi                      = {10.4271/981419},
  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.05.30}
}

@ARTICLE{View13,
  Title                    = {Vieweg Handbuch Kraftfahrzeugtechnik},
  Author                   = {H.-H. Braess, U. Seiffert (Hrsg.)},
  Editor                   = {H.-H. Braess, U. Seiffert},
  Publisher                = {Springer Fachmedien Wiesbaden},
  Year                     = {2013},

  Doi                      = {10.1007/978-3-658-01691-3_5},
  Owner                    = {fischermi},
  Timestamp                = {2014.12.09}
}

@ARTICLE{abgasdruck_tester_1,
  Title                    = {ATP-2204 Abgasdruck-Tester (Katalysator-Passage)},

  Author                   = {{Hans W. Meier GmbH}},
  HowPublished             = {online},
  Year                     = {2015},

  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.06.06},
  Url                      = {http://www.hwm.ch/downloads/121-abgas.pdf}
}

@ARTICLE{einbauspezifikation_audi,
  Title                    = {Einbauspezifikation Abgastemperatursensoren WSK.015.765. Version 1.5},

  Author                   = {Heijboer, B. and Reitzner, A.},
  HowPublished             = {Technische Entwicklung EAEK/1},
  Month                    = {03},
  Year                     = {2015},

  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.05.28}
}

@ARTICLE{Hering_elektronik,
  Title                    = {Elektronik für Ingenieure und Naturwissenschaftler},
  Author                   = {Hering, E. and Bressler, K. and Gutekunst, J.},
  Hrsg.                    = {J. Gutekunst},
  Publisher                = {Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 2014},
  Year                     = {2005},

  Doi                      = {10.1007/b137683},
  ISBN                     = {978-3-540-24309-0},
  Isbne                    = {978-3-540-26487-3},
  Owner                    = {Michael},
  Timestamp                = {2015.05.30},
  Url                      = {http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb137683}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[]{scrbook}


% ------------- Schrift --------------
% ------------------------------------------
\usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %% Schriftkodierung, die nativ Umlaute unterstützt 
\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref} % Querverweise mit Seitenreferenz
\usepackage[ngerman,
breaklinks]{hyperref} % Querverweise mit Seitenreferenz
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{  left=2.5cm,  right=2.5cm,  top=2.5cm,  bottom=3cm,  bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}



\usepackage[%
  backend      = biber, 
  maxnames     = 99, 
sorting=none, %  Mit der Einstellung sorting=none wird nicht sortiert, sondern die Einträge werden in der Reihenfolge, in der sie zitiert werden aufgeführt. 
  hyperref     = true, 
  maxcitenames = 2,
  mincitenames = 1,
  natbib       = true,
  giveninits   = true, % firstinits
  style        = numeric, 
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets, german=quotes]{csquotes}


%%\newrobustcmd{\mkbibslashes}[1]{/#1/}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{mkbibslashes}{\mkbibslashes{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}                  % no punct after entry

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibslashes]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}



%\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
%  {\list
%     {\ifentrytype{article}
%       {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{
%         \printtext[labelalphawidth]{% mkbibslashes
%           \printfield{prefixnumber}%
%           \printfield{labelalpha}%
%           \printfield{extraalpha}}%
%            %\addspace%
%            %\MakeSentenceCase{\thefield{entrytype}}%
%       }}
%       {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{% mkbibslashes
%          \printfield{prefixnumber}%
%          \printfield{labelalpha}%
%          \printfield{extraalpha}}}}
%     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%\labelnumberwidth or \labelalphawidth
%      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
%      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
%      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
%      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
%      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
%      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}% \hss##1
%  {\endlist}
%  {\item}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\printtext[bibhyperref]{#1}}



%% \DeclareNameFormat[article]{author}{\dotfill #1 \dotfill}
%\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\bf #1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\enquote{#1}}%\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\emph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{S.~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{#1}



\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}% 
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\RaggedRight}p{0.3\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.002\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.59\textwidth}}
  \printnames{author}\textsf{:} & 
  &  % um Abstand zu erh�hen
    \printfield{title}\newunit \printfield{year}\newunit  
    \printfield{journaltitle}\newunit \printfield{volume}\newunit
    \printfield{number}\newunit \printfield{pages}\newunit 
    \printfield{url}\newunit \printfield{doi}\newunit \\%
\end{tabular}
%\vspace{1em}% 1em
%\hrule
\usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\RaggedRight}p{0.3\textwidth}>p{0.02\textwidth}>{\RaggedRight}p{0.68\textwidth}}
  \printnames{author} &  
  &  % um Abstand zu erhöhen
    \printfield{title}\newunit \printfield{year}\newunit  
    \printfield{journaltitle}\newunit \printfield{volume}\newunit
    \printfield{number}\newunit \printfield{pages}\newunit 
    \printfield{url}\newunit \printfield{doi}\newunit \\%
\end{tabular}
%\vspace{1em}% 1em
%\hrule
\usebibmacro{finentry}}




\begin{document}
\nocite{*} % dadurch werden alle abgespeicherten Lit-Verzeichnis-Einträge aufgelistet (egal ob sie verwendet wurden)
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know a solution?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Kind regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}\hfill}
```

If you have more than 99 entries I would advise to add

```
\settowidth{\labelnumberwidth}{[999]}
```